# Terminate old Mist multisig contract?

Tags: mist, multisignature

It's been a while since I dealt with my (lost? thought) ETH. Now a new attempt :).

**The history:**

I had a Mist Wallet (on my Mac) many years ago and created a Contract there, where I have some ETH to this day.

**My attempt:**

I have access to my wallet and I would like to get the ETH from the contract into the wallet itself or send it to another wallet.

Now I have installed the MyCrypto desktop app, opened the wallet, found the "Contracts" tab. Now I want to interact with the contract and choose "Mist's Multisig Contract".

**Now to my question:**

What is the correct way to get the ETH out of the contract and into the wallet itself or transfer it to a new wallet? Unfortunately I can't find the documentation for all the functions.

Thanks in advance for your support!

Edit 1:
When I try to initiate a transfer, the **to** address seems to be wrong. Actually it's the same address as the contract.

[image]

[image]

Edit 2:
This is the confirmation window I get. The **From** is the wallet that holds the contract and the **To** is the contract address itself. That seems wrong, doesn't it?
[image]

Comment: I can't edit my post, so here's what I wanted to add: "Hello everyone!"

Comment: While not against the Code of Conduct, greetings are often removed due to their non-necessity;)

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for the clarification :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the MyCrypto pretty detailed post on this very specific topic : https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/sending/how-to-interact-with-a-multisig-contract/

The `m_required` function will return the number of signature needed, the `m_dailyLimit` the daily limit and you can send ETH via  `execute` (fill the value in _value, in wei, and leave the data and value fields empty).

Comment: I actually tried executing a transfer. But when I want to sign it and look at the details it says "To: [contract_address]". But I would mean that it should be "To: [other_wallet_address]". I added the screenshots above.

Comment: Those are different “to”, one is a function parameter (the one you choose as the recipient) and the other one is the actual transaction you send (including this parameter in the data) -> you are saying “to” the contract “transfer some eth “to” this address” (they could have used “recipient” as param name)

Comment: I see, but that is very misleading. Also, when I get the confirmation window (see screenshot above) it says that I want to send from the wallet (that holds the contract) to the contract. I still think that's either wrong or just a bad UI :D.

Comment: To fully get what's going on, you need to know that a multisig is just a smartcontract that you're interacting with -> if you want to transfer token out of it, you don't transfer them like you would from your address but rather interact with the multisig contract, asking it to do the transfer. In other word, the tx you see is you "asking the multisig to do a transfer", not the actual token/eth transaction

Comment: Thanks a lot! I successfully transferred the ETH to another wallet. first a small amount, then the rest. If I understand correctly, the "transfer" is just from the wallet to the contract, where the content of the transfer (the data part) contains the address of the recipient wallet and the amount. This has always puzzled me before, but now it is clear.